# AWS Elasticsearch Scripts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have a managed Elasticsearch (5.3) instance on AWS.
I want to do a sort on the results in Elasticsearch but i always get

```
TransportError(500, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'runtime error')
```

And i don't know why.
Looking into it in Kibana i get the following error.

```
"caused_by": {
  "type": "script_exception",
  "reason": "runtime error",
  "script_stack": [
    "org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.TextFieldMapper$TextFieldType.fielddataBuilder(TextFieldMapper.java:336)",
    "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:111)",
    "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:87)",
    "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$1.run(LeafDocLookup.java:84)",
    "java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)",
    "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:84)",
    "doc['value'].value.length()",
    "    ^---- HERE"
  ],
  "script": "doc['value'].value.length()",
  "lang": "painless",
  "caused_by": {
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [value] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."
  }
}
```

And my query is:

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "value"
      ],
      "query": "*a*"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "doc['value'].value.length()",
      "order": "asc",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
```

Do scripts work in AWS Elasticsearch?

I just want to order my results by the string length

Comment: try adding "fielddata": true in query

Comment: already did that => no result. I don't understand why scripts or dynamic scripts do not wok